# Find the odd and even functions of a function

Tags: calculus

Find the odd function and even function for the function that is equal to 1-x when x is between 0 and 1 and 0 elsewhere.

For this problem am I supposed to just plug in 1-x into the even function and 0 into the odd function. I believe that I am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the even part of a function is given by

$$f_e(x) = \frac{1}{2}(f(x)+f(-x))$$

and the odd part is given by

$$f_o(x) = \frac{1}{2}(f(x)-f(-x)).$$

From the definition of $f$, we can write it as

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1-x &0\le x\le 1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}.$$

Then

$$f(-x) = \begin{cases} 1-(-x) & 0 \le (-x) \le 1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$

Which we can rewrite as

$$f(-x) = \begin{cases} 1+x & -1 \le x \le 0 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$

Do you see what to do from here?

Comment: Am I supposed to plug in the 1-x into the even part of the function and then 0 into the odd part?

Comment: I have edited my post. Does this help?

Comment: Yes this clears things up!